# What is the simplest way to embed SPARQL query results into a web page?

Tags: php, python, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I want to add results of SPARQL queries to a web page using a server-side script. My server-side scripting is beginner-level, so the simpler the script, the better for now.

I've made some basic SPARQL queries using Snorql; I'm assuming this is an appropriate first step. My end goal is to have a portable, relatively simple php/python solution of making queries to datasets such as dbpedia, for output to a web page.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I was able to accomplish my original task, so I'll answer my own question.

I was able to output results from SPARQL queries on a web page using the **ARC2 PHP library**. 
Once I got everything working, I wrote a tutorial on it: [Creating HTML Web Pages from Linked Data Using PHP, SPARQL, and ARC2](http://matthewedward.blogspot.ca/2014/04/create-html-web-pages-linked-data-php-sparql-arc2.html)

Answer (score 0):

See the query examples at http://www.sparql.org/.  It uses client-side XSLT (there is a commonly used transform to get an HTML from the XML results published by the SPARQL working group).